# Create JavaFX ComboBox with custom Popup

Tags: javafx, combobox, popup

I want to write a ComboBox with a custom Node object inside its Popup (rather than the common ListView). ColorPicker and DatePicker are good examples, which are the other two implementations of ComboBoxBase. I had thought I could easily extend ComboBoxBase, too, but since there is no popupProperty or popupFactory I don't know how to set the content. How else is it meant to be done? Or how ColorPicker and DatePicker do this?

Comment: Take a look at `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin` +superclasses. Those are the classes responsible for the look of the popup... (look for the `createDefaultSkin` in the source code of a `Node` to find the skin used)

Comment: Just in case people still encounter the same problem, here is a thread with a working code snippet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622453/javafx-create-popover-without-external-libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ComboBoxPopupControl` which extends `ComboBoxBaseSkin` contains `getPopupContent()`. That's the method you are looking for. In your own skin implementation, which extends one of the ComboBoxSkins, you can return the popup content you like (although it's not recommended to use private API)

```
public class CustomComboBox<T> extends ComboBox<T> {

        @Override
        protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
            return new CustomComboBoxSkin<>(this);
        }
}

public  class CustomComboBoxSkin<T> extends ComboBoxPopupControl<T> {

        public CustomComboBoxSkin(ComboBox<T> comboBox) {
            super(comboBox, new CustomComboBoxBehaviour<>(comboBox));
        }

        @Override
        public Node getPopupContent() {
            return new Rectangle(150, 200);
        }

        // inherited methods ...

}
```

Comment: I see. But why do you say "not recommended"? I mean, how else should I exchange the ListView with e.g. a TableView, TreeView or something completely other?

Comment: It's not recommended to use private API, because its classes may change in a future release, which in turn can brake your code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874310/need-clarification-of-what-is-this-public-api-in-javafx . If you want to extend `ComboBox` I guess there is no other choice. But if you don't need the listview behaviour anyway, maybe it's an option to build your own custom control

Comment: With Java 9 skin api became public. So now extending ComboBoxPopupControl is a good and valid possibility.

Answer (score -1):

I used `ComtextMenu` to replace the commbox's popup like this:

```
ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
item.setGraphic(new Lable("test"));
menu.getItems.add(item);
commbox.setContextMenu(null);
commbox.setContextMenu(menu ); 
commbox.getContextMenu().show(comboBox, Side.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
```

It works fine.

Comment: I tried your code (after correcting all its errors). It has no effect. Shows the empty common ComboBox Popup and no ContextMenu at all. Forgot something?

Comment: you need a action to invoke the code, like `text.setOnKeyReleased(e->{ //add contextmenu here})`.